# IELTS score | secondary applicant & primary applicant

Tags: canada, ielts

Me & my husband approached IELTS for FSW last month.

My results:

```
Listening:  8.0
Reading:    7.0
Writing:    6.5
Speaking:   7.0
------------------
Overall:    7.0
```

My husband's results:

```
Listening:  6.0
Reading:    7.0
Writing:    5.5
Speaking:   6.0
-------------------
Overall:    6.0
```

one of a consultancy suggested me that either of us should get a 7 (primary applicant) n t other can be minimum 5.

In this case are we eligible for FSW with me as primary applicant and my husband will be secondary applicant?

Or else should he write the exam to get min score of 6 in each section? Please suggest us!

Answer (score 1):

First off I want to clear it out that there is no *minimum* requirement for the dependent (in this case your husband). So as long as you are meeting the [CLB 7](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/apply-who.asp) requirement (which you are) you should be okay.

However to improve your profile, you can always give the test again and have a higher score and better profile.

Comment: You can earn points if the spouse/secondary applicant scores well enough on a language test. You should check total scores if either of you have different education or work qualifications because the points for those may outweigh the language points.